# Multi color Edit Field (Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, text, colors

I want to create a program that will parse text for key words and make these words a certain color. What type of control supports many different colors? Would I have to create my own, or override the OnPaint() of a basic control or something? (Id like to avoid making my own control from scratch)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the rich edit control:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichEditLog_Demo.aspx

Another option would be to build a custom control:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/brainchild.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The standard rich-edit control will handle that quite easily.